# get indexes for selected values of boolean index

Tags: pandas

Consider the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[6, 3.14, 'c','d',4.2,'e']])
```

We can create an index for dtype by

```
boolIndex = df.dtypes=='object'
```

and create a subset directly with

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
```

As a learning exercise, I would like to create a data frame including columns corresponding to the first 2 (or an arbitrary number) TRUE values in boolIndex. Meaning, I would like to create a data frame including the first 2 columns of dtype 'object'. I am trying to avoid getting all the 'object' columns and then taking the first two. Ideally, I would have a numeric index corresponding to the positions, and I could select whichever ones I want.

Comment: "I am trying to avoid getting all the 'object' columns and then taking the first two." WHY?

Comment: Mainly as a learning exercise. But practically because my data set was large and I did not want to create another large data set. I just wanted to grab a few specific columns. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the first two object columns before slicing:

```
In [11]: objs = df.dtypes == 'object'

In [12]: objs[objs][:2].index
Out[12]: Int64Index([2, 3], dtype='int64')

In [13]: df.loc[:, objs[objs][:2].index]
Out[13]:
   2  3
0  c  d
```

Though I suspect the performance difference will be slight in most usecases, it could make a small difference in extreme cases:

```
In [21]: %timeit objs = df.dtypes == 'object'; df.loc[:, objs[objs][:2].index];
100 loops, best of 3: 5.03 ms per loop

In [22]: %timeit df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
10 loops, best of 3: 49.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: Note: this test was with 1000 times more columns.